How to solve this PDE involving polar coordinates?
PDE Equation with Polar Co-ordinates
I struggle with using polar coordinates. What method would I use here - is it just the Method of Characteristics? If so, what would be the way to proceed and how do polar coordinates change the usual method?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

You don't need to solve the PDE. All you have to do you is use the chain rule to calculate $f_{tt}$ via differentiating $u(t\cos\theta, t\sin\theta)$

Denoting $x=t\cos\theta$ and $y=t\sin\theta$ and using the chain rule on $f(\theta, t)$ when taking a partial derivative with respect to $t$, one obtains:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t\cos\theta, t\sin\theta) =
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
$$
Keeping in mind, that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ are also the functions of $x$ and $y$, let's take the second derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u(t\cos\theta, t\sin\theta) = \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
\Big(
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} 
\Big) = \\
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \Big(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\Big)^2 + 
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} 
+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2}
+ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\Big)^2 + 
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} 
+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}
= \\
u_{xx}\Big(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\Big)^2 + 
2u_{xy} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + 
u_{xy} \Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\Big)^2 +
u_{x}\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2} + 
u_{y}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}
$$
Now, clearly $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = \cos\theta$, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \sin\theta$, and the second partial derivatives w.r.t. to $t$ are zero, so taking the value of the former function at $t=0$, one gets:
$$ g(\theta) =
A\cos^2{\theta} + 
2B \cos{\theta}\sin{\theta} + 
C\sin^2{\theta} =
A\cos^2{\theta} + 
B\sin{2\theta} + 
C\sin^2{\theta}
$$
Finally, if you use the identities:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\cos^2{\theta} = \frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2} \\
\sin^2{\theta} = \frac{1-\cos2\theta}{2}
\end{array}
$$
and notice, that your integrate all the trigonometric function over their periods, they all cancel out, leaving only constant terms untouched. So:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(\theta)\, d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{A+C}\, d\theta = A+C
$$
